# Simplify PHP for SQL data retrevial

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP and SQL queries but trying to learn. Anyway, I have the following code which I'm sure there will be a simpler way of doing (hopefully as I intend to do the same for day of year not just month).

My current code is;

```
//Get jan power consumption
$janquery = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(kw*tdsecs) FROM data WHERE year(time) = year(CURDATE()) AND month(time) = 1");
$janresult = mysql_fetch_array($janquery);
$jankwm = $janresult[0] / 60;
$jankwh = round($jankwm / 60,2);

//Get feb power consumption
$febquery = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(kw*tdsecs) FROM data WHERE year(time) = year(CURDATE()) AND month(time) = 2");
$febresult = mysql_fetch_array($febquery);
$febkwm = $febresult[0] / 60;
$febkwh = round($febkwm / 60,2);
```

and so on then...

```
$values=array(
    "Jan" => $jankwh,
    "Feb" => $febkwh,
    "Mar" => $markwh,
    "Apr" => $aprkwh,
    "May" => $maykwh,
    "Jun" => $junkwh,
    "Jul" => $julkwh,
    "Aug" => $augkwh,
    "Sep" => $sepkwh,
    "Oct" => $octkwh,
    "Nov" => $novkwh,
    "Dec" => $deckwh
);
```

I want to avoid having 12 queries so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    month(time) as `month`, 
    SUM(kw*tdsecs) as `sum`
FROM data 
WHERE year(time) = year(CURDATE())
group by month(time)
order by month(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month(time), SUM(kw*tdsecs) FROM data 
WHERE year(time) = year(CURDATE()) group by month(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  mysql_query("SELECT month(time),SUM(kw*tdsecs) FROM data WHERE
  year(time) = year(CURDATE()) AND month(time) in
  (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) group by month(time)")
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (not the best) would be to loop through the months and store the results in a array:

```
for($month=1; $month<=12; $month++) {
  $query = mysql_query(
    "SELECT SUM(kw*tdsecs) FROM data 
     WHERE year(time) = year(CURDATE()) AND month(time) = $month");
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  $kwm[$month] = $result[0] / 60;
  $kwh[$month] = round($kwm[$month] / 60,2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. While it may or may not be the best way to do it it's saved me writing almost the same query 12 times for the monthly results and 31 times for the daily ones (and 365 times if I do the whole year - I assume I can loop for($day=1; $day<=31; $day++) etc. inside the $month loop)